# Calling overloaded scala case apply from java using java generic

Tags: java, scala, generics, interop

There are several methods I need to write in Java, most of the system is in scala.  Interop is not much of an issue except for one case.

I have a java method which takes a generic T in the call to a method, the generic being passed in is actually a scala case class.  The challenge I am having is calling the overloaded apply method of the case class from within the java code.  It cannot resolve the method apply.  I have tried several variations of an extends definition for T but none seem to solve the problem.

Any suggestions?  Here is a simplified version of the code so far:

Java (method in question)

```
public <T> Option<T> getResult(String name) {
    Iterator<Item> items = repo.results(name).iterator();

    if (items.hasNext()) {
        T model = T.apply(items.next());  // ?? how to call overloaded case class apply method
        return new Some<>(model);
    }

    return scala.Option$.MODULE$.apply(null);
}
```

Scala case class (with overloaded apply method), one of many possible case classes.

```
case class Person (id: Int, name: String)

object Person {
  def apply(item: Item) = toObject(item)

  def toObject(item: Item): Person = {
    Person(
      item.getProperty[Int]("id"),
      item.getProperty("name")
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You need an instance of `Person` and you have to up-bound the type parameter.

Comment: is `T` supposed to be a any case class or always `Person` (in which case you wouldn't need generics)

Comment: @kocko I tried `public <T extends Person> Option<T> getResult(String name)` but then the error on the line in question is `Required T but found Person`.  Also, I would not want to use Person because there are many case class types that could be passed in.  If I use a base class for them, I can't define an abstract apply method for a base case class companion object in scala.  Am I missing something, can you provide example code? Thanks.

Comment: @Chirlo there can be many case class types, so do need generic. If I remove the generic and just use a typed param of Person, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. Java generics are erased at runtime, so in order to do something like `T.apply`, you'd need an instance of the `T`, so your method would look like:

   `public <T> Option<T> getResult(String name, T t)`
2. You need an upper bound where the `apply` method would be defined to ensure that you can call the method on `T`. However, scala declares this in the companion object, which is a separate class from the class it accompanies. And there's no super class for companion objects that describes which `apply` methods they should implement.

The only thing I could think of is, if you known that the `apply` method takes only 1 parameter:

```
public <T> Option<T> getResult(String name, Function1<Item, T> companion){ // this is extended by companion objects of case class that take only 1 parameter
 ... 
  T model = companion.apply(items.next());
 ...
}
```

With this approach, you'd call the method like this:

```
 getResult("name", Person$.MODULE$)  //pass the companion object as a factory
```

Comment: @Chiro Thanks that worked - just needed to adjust one line in your code: `public <T> Option<T> getResult(String name, Function1<Item, T> companion)` the wrong braces - the problem with switching between languages :), also needed define a base abstract class for T classes with fake apply() method to keep java happy.  I would really like to get rid of passing the companion apply method but one setup at a time.